# Intellij gradle compiling storing very large index

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using Intellij Idea and Gradle to compile my Android Apps and I've noticed my computer was slowing down and I found out it was because Idea was creating two large (1.1GB) files and my harddrive was getting full.

```
~/.IdeaIC13/system/Maven/Indices/Index1
~/.IdeaIC13/system/Maven/Indices/Index2
```

So I tried doing File > Invalidate Caches / Restart, but that didn't delete them. So I deleted the folders manually, but after running Idea again and compiling it recreated them.

I could solve this problem by allocating some more space but I'd rather know what is going on and if I can be fixed. Thanks

Comment: I see this bug for it, but there's not detail: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-51969

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the indices would result in IDEA rebuilding the indices automatically, and should be smaller as the obsolete projects/repositories will not be indexed.

It made a significant difference for me.

Source: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/requests/32695

This answer may be obsolete for future versions of the IDE, but it certainly applies to v13, at least.

Comment: The source link no longer seems to exist.